# Global Alignment sequence

Tags: python

I am doing global alignment of DNA sequences. I have prepared a global alignment matric 'C' using pre defined rules.

Suppose Seq1 = [1,1,4,4,1] and Seq3 = [1,1,4,1].

Image for a path[Global Alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVZAZ.png). 
Its obtained by adding 2 on diagonal if elements of Seq 1 and 2 match and subtracting 1 if they don't.

So a possible **alignment output** would be s1 = AACCA and s2 = A-ACA, which is not printing. The values referenced from dictionary are not getting included in the s1 and s2. If I type in console, `s1 = dict[Seq1[4]] + s1`, I'm able to add character 'C' in s1. However, after putting it in while loop, it's not getting added in s1 or s2.

```
# Global Alignment
import numpy as np
Set = [1,2,3,4]
#defining DNA characters as 1,2,3,4
dict = {1:'A', 2:'T', 3:'G', 4:'C'}
Seq1 = [1,1,4,4,1]
Seq3 = [1,1,4,1]

#Assigning values to Mismatch, Gap and Match
Mismatch = -1
Match = 2 
Gap = -1

#Global Alignment Matrix
m = len(Seq1)
n = len(Seq3)
C = np.array([[0 for j in range(n+1)] for i in range (m+1)]) # Creating a zero matrix
for i in range(0,m+1):
    C[i][0] = i * Gap
for i in range(0,n+1):
    C[0][i] = i * Gap

for i in range(0,m):
    for j in range(0,n):
        if Seq1[i] == Seq3[j]:
            C[i+1][j+1] = C[i][j] + Match
        else:
            C[i+1][j+1] = max(C[i][j] + Mismatch, C[i+1][j] + Gap, C[i][j+1] + Gap)

# From here values are not getting included in s1 and s2 after being referenced from dictionary
s1 = ""
s2 = ""
i = len(Seq1)
j = len(Seq3)

while (not(i != -1 or j != -1)):
    if (C[i][j] == C[i-1][j-1] + Match): 
        s1 = dict[Seq1[i-1]] + s1
        s2 = dict[Seq3[j-1]] + s2
        i=i-1
        j=j-1
    elif (C[i][j] == C[i-1][j-1] + Mismatch):
        s1 = dict[Seq1[i-1]] + s1
        s2 = dict[Seq2[j-1]] + s2
        i=i-1
        j=j-1
    elif (C[i][j] == C[i][j-1] + Gap):
        s1 = dict[Seq1[i-1]] + s1
        s2 = '-' + s2
        i=i-1   
    elif (C[i][j] == C[i-1][j] + Gap):
        s1 = '-' + s1
        s2 = dict[Seq3[j-1]] + s2
        j=j-1
```

Comment: changed the code towards the end for backtracking, but values are still not getting included in s1 and s2

Comment: You need to make a [mre] including the full error message with traceback. Check out [ask] for more tips.